# Prove that another matrix is inverse of $A+BCD$

Tags: matrices

Given $\mathrm{A} \in \mathbb{F}^{n \times n}, \; \mathrm{B} \in \mathbb{F}^{n \times k}, \; \mathrm{C} \in \mathbb{F}^{k \times k}, \; \mathrm{D} \in \mathbb{F}^{k \times n}$, and $\mathrm{A, \;C}$ are invertible.

Prove that $\mathrm{\left(A + BCD\right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}B\left(C^{-1}+DA^{-1}B\right)^{-1}DA^{-1}}$

I proved it by showing,

$$
\mathrm{\left(A + BCD\right)^{-1}\left( A^{-1} - A^{-1}B\left(C^{-1}+DA^{-1}B\right)^{-1}DA^{-1} \right) - I = O}
$$,
and the solution in the textbook support this idea.

But why isn't it necessary to prove $$
\mathrm{\left( A^{-1} - A^{-1}B\left(C^{-1}+DA^{-1}B\right)^{-1}DA^{-1} \right)\left(A + BCD\right)^{-1} - I = O}
$$ also?

Comment: Do you mean $(BCD)^{-1}$? Because there is no way D is invertible.

Comment: More generally, one can prove that in a group, being a left inverse implies being a right inverse.

Comment: @SeanRoberson typo. sorry.

Comment: @user293121 a specific Wikipedia page to point to?

Answer (score 0):

For square matrices, if $AB = I$ then $BA = I$.